# FreeQ with symbolic condition

Tags: pattern-matching, functional-style, expression-test

I'm having a problem:

```
FreeQ[a, _?(# < 0 &)]
```

returns `True` when `a` is kept symbolic.

Shouldn't it hold somehow, returning a conditional expression. How can I make this happen with `FreeQ`?

---

P.S.: I am not interested in alternative functions, I just want to understand this behavior.

Comment: You really ought to be doing `FreeQ[a, _?(# < 0 &)]`.

Comment: You are right (edited), but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FreeQ[a, _?(a < 0 &)]` is a very odd expression.  What exactly is that *supposed* to do?

With `a` symbolic (unassigned) `a < 0` does not evaluate, and therefore it is not `True`, i.e. `TrueQ[a < 0]` evaluates to `False`.  [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) only matches on an explicit `True`, therefore `_?(a < 0 &)` will match nothing until `a` has a value.  Since the pattern represents an empty set `a` is free of it.

---

I see that you fundamentally changed the question.

As noted in the first part of my answer `PatternTest` matches only on an explicitly `True` return of its test function.  Since `a < 0` does not evaluate it does not match.

Comment: So how can I make it return a condition on `a`?

Comment: @MaPo `FreeQ`, like most (all?) `*Q` functions returns either `True` or `False`.   It is not the correct tool to return a conditional expression.  Have you looked at `Reduce`, `Resolve`, etc.?